# Setting knitr to output separate images

Tags: r, png, knitr

I'm trying to get the PNG plots from knitr output to write to disk as separate files without doing it manually.

#### What I tried

- The `dev = 'png'` setting from http://gforge.se/2014/01/fast-track-publishing-using-knitr-part-iii/ (also mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954647/dev-png-is-not-working-for-pdf-output-in-knitr))
- `self_contained: no` from [knitr: include figures in report *and* output figures to separate files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992239/knitr-include-figures-in-report-and-output-figures-to-separate-files).

Neither worked. The folder the knitting process ran in has no extra files, and the HTML document has base64 embedded images in its source.

#### Environment

- RStudio 0.99.903
- R 3.2.3
- knitr 1.15.1

#### MWE: The RStudio RMarkdown file, with abovementioned options added:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
self_contained: no
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev="png", 
                      dev.args=list(type="cairo"),
                      dpi=96)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Comment: Worth highlighting here another solution which saves all `ggplot` s from `.Rmd`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77563203/how-to-save-all-ggplots-of-a-rmd-as-rds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self_contained` is an option for `html_document`, not a top-level YAML setting.  The document below works using just that.  PNG is the default figure type, so you don't need to specify that.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  html_document:
    self_contained: no
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````