# How to save all ggplots of a `.Rmd` as `.rds`

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I use markdown documents for my analyses. I create lots of plots and use
`knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev= c("png", "svg", "pdf")` and `rmarkdown::render(... , clean = FALSE)` to obtain png ( for use with google slides) , svg (for use with powerpoint) and pdf (to be included in manual latex reports). However, I would now like to combine plots from different analyses into figure panels while being able to change plot sizes and aspect ratios without rerunning all the analyses each time.

One way to achieve this is to save the ggplots in `.rds` files using `saveRDS(ggplot2::last_plot(), "figure_1.rds")` in the analysis notebooks and `library(patchwork); readRDS("figure_1.rds") / readRDS("figure_2.rds")` in a separate script generating the figure panels. This could partially be automated using a hook:

`example_analysis.Rmd`

````
```{r setup}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev= c("png", "svg", "pdf")
knitr::knit_hooks$set(hook_save_plot_as_rds = function(before, options, envir, name) {
  if(before) return() # run only after chunk
  if(length(knitr:::get_plot_files())==0) return() # only run if 
  saveRDS(ggplot2::last_plot(), knitr::fig_chunk(knitr::opts_chunk$get("label"), ext = "rds"))
})
```
Here we do some heavy analysis
```{r sepal-plot}
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + geom_point()
```

Here we do some more heavy analysis
```{r petal-plot}
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length)) + geom_point()
```
````

Somewhere else:

```
library(patchwork)
get_figure <- function(name) readRDS(paste0("example_analysis_files/figure-html/", name, "-1.rds"))
get_figure("petal-plot") / get_figure("sepal-plot") + plot_annotation(tag_levels="A")
```

[image]

But that only works for the last ggplot of each chunk. Is there a way that works for all plots of chunk? Is there maybe a hidden `device="rds"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is actually quite simple: the right place to do this is not an extra device or some hooks, but the print function. knitr provides the [`knit_print` S3 generic](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/opts-render.html) that gives control over how R objects are printed by knitr. One can simply add a `knit_print.ggplot` that also saves the plot.

I knew yihui must have made this possible.

Full example:

example_analysis.Rmd

````
---
title: "example_analysis"
output: 
  html_document:
    keep_md: yes
---

```{r setup}
local({ # to keep global environment uncluttered
  counter <- NA
  previous_label <- NA
  print_and_save.ggplot <- function(x, ...) {
    ret <-  print(x, ...)
    current_label <- knitr::opts_current$get("label")
    if(isTRUE(previous_label==current_label)) {
      counter <<- counter+1 # keep track of plot number
    } else { # reset plot number for each new chunk
      previous_label <<- current_label
      counter <<- 1
    }
    dir.create(knitr::opts_current$get("fig.path"), recursive = TRUE, showWarnings = FALSE)
    saveRDS(ret, knitr::fig_path(suffix = "rds", number = counter))
    invisible(ret)
  }
  library(knitr)
  registerS3method("knit_print", "ggplot", print_and_save.ggplot)
})
library(ggplot2)
```

Here we do some heavy analysis
```{r sepal-plot}
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, fill= Species)) + geom_point()
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, fill= Species)) + geom_histogram() + coord_flip()
```

Here we do some more heavy analysis
```{r petal-plot}
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length, fill= Species)) + geom_point()
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, fill= Species)) + geom_histogram() + coord_flip()
```
````

somewhere else:

```r
library(patchwork)
get_figure <- function(name, idx = 1) readRDS(paste0("example_analysis_files/figure-html/", name, "-", idx,".rds"))
(get_figure("petal-plot") + get_figure("petal-plot", 2))  / (get_figure("sepal-plot") + get_figure("sepal-plot", 2)) + plot_annotation(tag_levels="A")
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like we worked out the same solution at almost the same time.  There's one major flaw in mine which is a minor flaw in yours:  the numbering of plots.  There's no easy way to find out the plot numbers that knitr will use.  You did sequential counts within each chunk.  That's usually right, but I think those will be wrong if the chunk contains other kinds of graphics as well as ggplots:  base graphics for sure, and maybe leaflet, plotly, rgl, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by setting up a `knit_print` method for `ggplot` objects.  Here's a simple example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "2023-11-28"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

# You can't see the knitr plot numbers, because they aren't determined until
# all the plotting is done.  We'll just use a simple sequential numbering.

plotnum <- 0

knit_print.ggplot <- function(x, options) {
  # Get a new plot number
  plotnum <<- plotnum + 1

  # Save the ggplot object to a file based on the chunk label and plot number

  saveRDS(x, paste0(options$label,"-", plotnum, ".rds"))

  # Now do the regular print method.
  print(x)
}
```

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_point() + ggtitle("First")
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_point() + ggtitle("Second")
```
````

Edited to add:

@jan-glx posted a much more complete solution at around the same time; I recommend his solution over this one for actual use, but I like this one for illustrating the idea in simple code.

Comment: Nice, you beat me to it! In my self answer below I (1) used an anonymous function to store the `plotnum` and (2) reset it for each chunk by observing the chunk label. This has the advantage that the global environment remains uncluttered (by 1)  and that the filenames are much more stable (2). Would it be OK for you if I replace your answer by mine, delete mine and accept yours?

Comment: No, you should just accept your own answer.  I think it's better if people see both.

Comment: true, yours is much less in a need of TLDR than mine

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to include the following in each chunk

```
plot_label = opts_current$get("label")
saveRDS(ggplot2::last_plot(), paste0(plot_label, ".rds")
```

Which will save that plot object to the given RDS.

To avoid duplicate code, you can wrap this in a function

```
save_plot <- function() {
  plot_label = opts_current$get("label")
  saveRDS(ggplot2::last_plot(), paste0(plot_label, ".rds")
}
```

Which would look something like

````
```{r petal-plot}
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length)) + geom_point()
save_plot()
```
````

Then when you want the plots available, load them using your method of choice, e.g. using using `list.files(pattern = "*.rds")`

Comment: How is this d̶i̶f̶f̶e̶r̶e̶n̶t̶ f̶r̶o̶m̶ better as the approach in the question?

Comment: Not necessarily better, just an alternative solution not relying on hooks. As far as I know, there is no `RDS` device.

Comment: that is what the hook solution n the question does as well, with the added benefit that you do not need to add that line to every chunk.

Comment: This would work for all plots in the chunk, given that you use `save_plot` after each plot.

Comment: not true. the second would override the first. (sorry for the comment upvote)